# Launch standard buttton from record triggered flow

Tags: leads, lead-conversion, recordtriggeredflow

Is there any way to launch the convert button on a lead when the field lead status is updated to QUALIFIED?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't call a button, quick action, etc from a Record-Triggered Flow. However, you can convert the lead automatically using various strategies. Take a look at our [search](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=lead+convert+automatically) for potential solutions. Most people just use triggers, I think, but you could write some Apex code that can then be called from a flow.